# MySQL - Fetching more records when ordered by integer

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm writing an application to fetch records from the database, and my client has asked if I could sort the data by area. I've got the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customers
WHERE 
    account_type != 'x'
AND 
    account_type != 'tor'
ORDER BY 
    area ASC,
    id ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

The query returns 30 rows worth of data, all with an area value of `1`.

I've got an AJAX query set up to fetch another 30 rows, however as I am ordering the data by area, I am unable to just fit a simple range string to my query as shown in the example below:

```
...
AND
    id > 30
...
```

How would I write a query that would collect the next 30 records from the database?

Also, there is a record with an area value of `0`. This is not shown as the first record in the list. Why is this? And how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and expected output please.

Comment: If you think adding `AND id > 30` was the right way to do pagination, then you are doing it wrong to begin with. You work with LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: _“Also, there is a record with an area value of 0. This is not shown as the first record in the list.”_ – is it `0`, or is it `NULL`? Those are two _completely_ different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, combine the `where` conditions into a single `not in`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE account_type NOT IN ('x', 'tor')
ORDER BY area ASC, id ASC 
LIMIT 30;
```

Then, for the next set, use:

```
SELECT . . .
OFFSET 30
LIMIT 30
```

This assumes that `id` is unique in the table.  That is important, because that makes the sort stable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the the SELECT query documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

In summary, just `limit` returns you x records. With the offset you can set a starting position, basically allows you for paging.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL LIMIT take an optional parameter offset, so you could send in a parameter telling where to start when picking the 30 results you want

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customers
WHERE 
    account_type != 'x'
AND 
    account_type != 'tor'
ORDER BY 
    area ASC,
    id ASC 
LIMIT 30, 30
```

Should give you the next 30 rows starting from row 30